# Why do I get the "Class not registered" error on chrome on trying to open a php or JS file?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I have been recently trying to open the PHP or JS files(any JS or PHP) file and it shows the "Class Not Registered " error. I have absolutely no idea how to fix it. I have tried deleting the registry keys for chrome. It still doesn't fix it.I have also tried re-installing chrome but doesn't help.
[Heres a screenshot please check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPHwj.png)

Comment: can you make a screenshot?

Comment: Yea i added a screenshot ..please help. @Hobroker

Comment: I don't think that's chrome's fault. Maybe there's another default app for opening those files?

Comment: another application?

Comment: i tried reinstlling chrome..doesnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hie Sourav,

You need to host the project ATTENDANCE MANAGEMENT in wamp/xampp first.

To work with php files.

Then you can use by : http://localhost/ATTENDANCE MANAGEMENT/validate.php